# Is it possible to access GPIO pins from a Python script and a C++ program at the same time?

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a Python script and a C++ program running at the same time, both accessing the GPIO pins (not the same ones, though) in this order:

1. C++
2. Python
3. C++

The access of the C++ program worked (I used wireless transmitters and received the message). After that the Python access (light up an LED) worked as well. But when I tried to send another message using the wireless transmitters with C++, nothing happened, I don't receive messages anymore.

Is there a way to find out, whether the GPIO pins are blocked or something?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running GPIO.cleanup() at the end of your Python script? (I think you should be)

I recently had a similar problem with a program in C. Does the problem happen when you *don't* run the Python script in between the two uses of the program in C++, too? Are you cleaning up your memory in the C++ program? Running delete[] and return 0 and such. Maybe run valgrind on it.

You can try to read input from the GPIOs from the shell with

```
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio0/value
```

(as root!)

Also, though I don't think you would have been able to turn on your LED without it, imho Python needs to be run as root to access the GPIOs. But maybe it's working without that and not able to cleanup? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you clean up the GPIO Headers in both scripts, it should be possible, otherwise it wont work.

You can clean up in python by using GPIO.cleanup(), then it sould work, cause it is clean again to your c++ Code.